# Is my shower wall sound enough for an overlay?

Tags: bathroom

How do I know if my existing tile wall is sound enough to do a thin panel stone wall overlay in my shower?  How do I check to ensure the structure is safe to do this overlay?

Comment: This depends on the type of stone, what their instructions are, their install method, and so on.  And what do you mean by safe?  We need more info to answer this.

Comment: It is a thin travertine (1/4 inch thick veneer on PVC waterproof backer board) and I want to just put it up over my tile.  I just want to be sure it is going to stay?  It is a house flip so I want to be in and out.

Comment: What about your wall makes you think it isn't stable?  Do you have a picture?

Comment: nothing really I just wanted to be certain.  I was just wondering if there was a "technique" or tool I cold use to be sure everything is sound.  Since I'm flipping it, I just want to be sure it's safe.